# gcloud components list not up-to-date?

Tags: gcloud

### Context

I will rely on a component shipped with Gcloud SDK CLI.

For migration purposes and other reasons, I want to know which version of the `cloud-sdk` starts shipping this component and avoid the "install the latest version".

### My issue

In the official changelog: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes, there are no references to the component I am looking for.

### Tries

I have tried to run this command naively

```
for gcloud_version in 390.0.0-alpine 391.0.0-alpine 392.0.0-alpine 393.0.0-alpine; do
  echo "---> ${gcloud_version}"
  docker run --rm -ti  google/cloud-sdk:${gcloud_version} gcloud components list
done
```

Unfortunately, every list do not show the component I am waiting for (even the latest version of `gcloud`, 393 at the time of writting).

### Discovery

However, when I run `gcloud components install MY_UNLISTED_COMPONENT` it works ...

Not a very reliable way to find out which version has the component I want.

Do you know if:

- this is an issue?
- I can report this somewhere?
- It is relevant to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the name of the public albeit unlisted component in your question. The [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) includes a "Send Feedback" option and you may want to provide this feedback there.

Comment: You can use `gcloud components list --format` to format (and then `grep` from) the list of components, `gcloud components list --format="value(id)" 2> /dev/null | grep ${UNLISTED_COMPONENT}`

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, Thanks for your answer.

The missing component is `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`

And even after having it installed, the command you provided did not return any data to me.

Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: That `gcloud` command will only return values once `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` is part of the components list. It's a reasonable question. `gcloud components install` is becoming rather overloaded with not-really `gcloud` components. I think, given that Google encourages using `gcloud components install` to install it (albeit for Windows and MacOS but not Linux), it's reasonable to expect it to be documented. I encourage you to send feedback via the release page and to consider filing an issue on Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: My experience (having installed `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` independently of `gcloud` on Linux) is that it's not dependent on a specific `gcloud` release so it's unclear how Google intends users to track this component.

Comment: The gcloud changelog's feedback module is not working well for me  :)
I was not able to write and submit anything.

Anyway, I have tried via the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239589367

Will see how it goes.

Thanks @DazWilkin for your time!

Answer (score -1):

From @DazWilkin

> It would be helpful if you included the name of the public albeit unlisted component in your question. The [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) includes a "Send Feedback" option and you may want to provide this feedback there.

> it's reasonable to expect it to be documented. I encourage you to send feedback via the release page and to consider filing an issue on Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).